# "[Me]" variable for custom field alerts in TFS 2013

Tags: tfs, tfs-alerts

I added a custom field (Test Prime) in `TFS`. Since I wanted a drop down of valid `TFS` users, I copied the setup of the Assigned To control `(String, Dimension, ALLOWEXISTINGVALUE, VALIDUSER, and SYNCNAMECHANGES)`. I want to be able to set up an alert triggered when:

```
Test Prime Changes to [Me] or Test Prime Changes from [Me]
```

but "[Me]" or "@Me" does not seem to grab the current user. It's under the drop down menu of Assigned To so I don't see why I can't get access to this variable. Is it because this is for a non-core field and [Me] is only available for core fields? If yes, is there a workaround because I haven't been able to find any.

Comment: Do you have syncnamechanges="true" attribure in your custom field definition? E.g. <FIELD name="Test Prime" refname="My.TestPrime" type="String" reportable="dimension" syncnamechanges="true" >
This attribute tells TFS that this is a user field.

Comment: I do now but "[Me]" or "@Me" still doesn't work.

Comment: Alerts trigger only on core fields. How do you make it work on a custom?

Answer (score 2):

1. set the `syncnamechanges="true"` in the custom field definition. If the workitem template cannot be uploaded, use the witadmin tool to update the syncnamechanges attribute.
2. in the alert rule, use `@@MyDisplayName@@` placeholder instead of `[Me]` or `@Me`.

Comment: just be careful about the space after @@MyDisplayName@@. I spent an hour for finding it in alerts

Comment: also this property can be updated with witadmin.exe with below commands
path %PATH%;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE;
witadmin changefield /collection:"<Collection>" /n:"<Filed Ref>" /syncnamechanges:true /noprompt